# gdb and ffmpeg compilation

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, gdb

I installed ffmpeg using the instructions of the web site ffmpeg: http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide, compilation works fine, they generates a file "ffmpeg_201207131721-git-1_amd64.deb " then, I excute

```
sudo dpkg-i ffmpeg_201207131721-git-1_amd64.deb
```

When I excute the command

```
ffmpeg -i -f toto.flv mp3-vn-acodec copy new_video.mp3
```

file "new_video. mp3" is well established. I would like to know what is the command "gdb" that I could use to find the file that have been consulted when i run the command `ffmpeg -i -f toto.flv mp3-vn-acodec copy new_video.mp3`

Thank you in advance

Toufik

Comment: gdb is "Gnu Debugger". Its used for source level debugging. Why you want to use it here?

Comment: I would like to modify the source code of ffmpeg. I would like to know the files and functions that are called at run ffmpeg command. I inserted the printf () but they are not considered

Comment: In a project coded in C, how I could know the functions called  when i excute  in terminal command of project
thank you in advance.
Toufik

Comment: what do mean by "files are called"?

Comment: have you considered this tutorial? http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html .

Answer (score 1):

To debug ffmpeg code i suggest the following steps in Linux:

1) get the latest version of ffmpeg: 
   wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2

2) 'untar' ffmpeg package:
tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2

3) configure ffmpeg without optimization options (in order to enable debugging), e.g. 
./configure  --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-optimizations --disable-mmx --disable-stripping

4) make

5) sudo make install

6) gdb  ffmpeg 
....

Comment: I'd add that `--enable-debugging=3 --prefix=/dome/path` also is usefull, 'coz system-wide installation is something quite hard to cleanup later

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you do a `make install` each time after modifying FFmpeg, or else your changes will not be reflected - this is likely why your printf() lines are not working.